# Error in requiring controllers in routes [nodejs]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, request

I created a user controller inside a controller folder for a node js app and trying to include it into my routes and I keep getting this error message, it was working all right and then all of a sudden it decided not to, I have looked through the code thoroughly for anything possible that could cause the malfunction to no avail.

here is the error

```
Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

and below are the files

controller file ./controller/user.js

```
// controller/user.js file


exports.login = function(req, res){
    res.render('auth/login');
}

exports.register = function(req, res){
    res.render('auth/register');
}

exports.reset = function(req, res){
    res.render('auth/reset');
}
```

routes file ./config/routes.js

```
// routes.js
var user = require('../controllers/user');
var home = require('../controllers/home');

module.exports = function(app){

// user login
app.get('/app/login', user.login);

// user registration
app.get('/app/register', user.register);

// user password reset
app.get('/app/reset', user.reset);
}
```

app.js

```
// ./app.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// const logger = function(req, res, next){
//     console.log('Loggin');
//     next();
// };

// app.use('logger')

// View Engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// Static path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Global Vars
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.errors = null;
    next();
});


// Routes
require('./config/routes')(app);

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('Server started on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: How are you invoking this function in your application: ***module.exports = function(app)*** i.e where and how do you call it?

Comment: Its been invoked here inside the app.js file

    // ./app.js

Added to the question edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the paths to the controllers in the route.js file.

You are referencing `require('../controllers/user')` instead of `require('../controller/user')` maybe you also need to fix the path to home controller.